# Write 2 button in HTML DOM on the right side of the screen from left to right

Tags: html, button, sequence-alignment

I wrote my DOM structure like :

```
 <button style="float:right">button1</button>
 <button style="float:right">button2</button>
 <button style="float:left">button3</button>
 <button style="float:left">button4</button>
```

and it will display like : https://jsfiddle.net/ospv6vn8/3/

button3 button4                                             button2 button1

but i want to render them like :

button4 button3                                             button1 button2

I can't modify my DOM structure, yes I can edit styles to get the desired look.

Comment: just change the text button4 to button3..you need 4 button together ?

Comment: According to my problem. DOM must remain same like button 1,2,3,4 but I want it to render as button4 button3 button1 button2.
where button 4 and 3 are on left side of screen and 1 and 2 are on right side of the screen

Comment: it is not possible

Comment: Can we make it by changing the style, position of the element via styles.

Comment: you want button 4 3 together ?

Comment: look this output and then tell what u want now [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ikishan/ospv6vn8/23/)

Comment: Okey,
but this is not the desired output.
My desired output is :
button4 button3 <-- on left side --same row-- on right side --> button1 button2

Comment: i think it is not possible to do without changing DOM struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED: THIS WORKS!
You could have the first ones use px instead of float and have button 3 float center, like this:

```
<button style="position: absolute; right: 61px;">button1</button>
<button style="position: absolute; right: 0px;">button2</button>
<button style="float:center;">button3</button>
<button style="float:left;">button4</button>
```

(always have button1 61px more to the right than button2)

Comment: same thing !! In this case buttons are not come together.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but still not getting the desired output

https://jsfiddle.net/utwz76cy/

here on the right side I want to display **button1 button2** instead of button2 button1

Comment: Use px instead of float for the first two, that should work. Always have button1 be 61px more to the right

Comment: Kishan oza that has a slight space inbetween, as it uses percentages then on each screen size it will look different, better to use px as it will stay the same

Comment: You could have the first ones use px instead of float and have button 3 float center, like this:
<button style="position: absolute; right: 61px;">button1</button>
<button style="position: absolute; right: 0px;">button2</button>
<button style="float:center;">button3</button>
<button style="float:left;">button4</button>
(always have button1 61px more to the right than button2)

Comment: Guys, using hard coded pixel value is a bad solution. :(

Comment: I am researching about some CSS properties that would do work for me

Comment: Fairly sure its the only way but if you find anything post it! i'd be interested to see